# Data buffering in multithreaded java application

Tags: java, java.util.concurrent

I have a multi threaded application which has one producer thread and several consumer threads.
The data is stored in a shared thread safe collection and flushed to a database when there is sufficient data in the buffer.

From the javadocs -

```
BlockingQueue<E>
```

A Queue that additionally supports operations that wait for the queue to become non-empty when retrieving an element, and wait for space to become available in the queue when storing an element.

```
take()
```

Retrieves and removes the head of this queue, waiting if necessary until an element becomes available.

My questions -

> 1. Is there another collection that has a E[] take(int n) method? i.e. Blocking queue waits until an element is available. What I want is
>      that it should wait until 100 or 200 elements are available.
> 2. Alternatively, is there another method I could use to address the problem without polling?

Comment: Should the elements be distributed equally to each consumer, or should the first consumer to the take method get the first `n` elements, the second consumer the next `n` elements, etc. ?

Comment: Is this really what you want to do? This can introduce almost arbitrarily large latency between data being produced and being flushed to the database if the rate of production ever slows beyond what you end up tuning for. If you really do need to do this buffering at all your logic should probably be more like "Wait till I have N elements or X ms have passed"

Comment: Why do you want to wait? Why not just use `drain()`? I would write all the data you have available up to some maximum and I would prefer not to lose data.

Comment: @SimonC all the consumers should get same set of data. Data that has been delivered to all should be removed. That's why so far none of the solutions proposed is helping me. Anyway still a lot of knowledge to glean through them. :-)

Comment: @DRMacIver Production rate is not a problem. It is a chemical sensor with a fixed rate of .5 secs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the only way is to either extend some implementation of `BlockingQueue` or create some kind of utility method using `take`:

```
public <E> void take(BlockingQueue<E> queue, List<E> to, int max) 
        throws InterruptedException {

    for (int i = 0; i < max; i++)
        to.add(queue.take());
}
```

Comment: Actually, your approach is much saner than mine, assuming that there is only ever going to be one consumer.

Comment: This approach doesn't deal well with InterruptedException at all because you lose any elements taken if interrupted. It really needs to be adding elements to a passed in collection if it's not going to handle the interrupt itself, or to catch and return the elements drained so far if it does want to.

Answer (score 2):

The `drainTo` method isn't exactly what you're looking for, but would it serve your purpose?

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html#drainTo(java.util.Collection, int)

*EDIT*

You could implement a slightly more performant batch blocking takemin using a combination of `take` and `drainTo`:

```
public <E> void drainTo(final BlockingQueue<E> queue, final List<E> list, final int min) throws InterruptedException
{
  int drained = 0;
  do 
  {
    if (queue.size() > 0)
      drained += queue.drainTo(list, min - drained);
    else
    {
      list.add(queue.take());
      drained++;
    }
  }
  while (drained < min);
}
```

Comment: as mentioned in another answer (which is now removed apparently) this is quite what he/she wants to do.

Comment: I've updated the answer to indicate that it doesn't solve the exact question.  Sometimes the OP isn't aware of alternative solutions though, so it's always worth asking.

Comment: I wouldn't dare to say that this this is even slightly faster... You are taking and releasing the underlying `lock` several times (checking size, using drainTo and take methods). Also this implementation would rely on that `drainTo` method is not implemented using a series of `take`s... which you cannot guarantee :)

Comment: @dacwe, any 'sensible' implementation of `drainTo` should perform either the same as `take` if there is a single element, or better if there are more than one element.  It would have to be an odd implementation for that not be the case.  Also, by your same argument, there's no guarantee there'll be a lock taken out for calls to any of the methods (there may be other synchronisation methods used).

Comment: Yes, you are correct, but my comment was, if it is implemented using a series of `take`s you also have the size-checking that requires some kind of locking. *In every day use it will be faster however (faster than using `take` anyways). In some odd corner case, I don't know..*

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if there's a similar class in the standard library that has `take(int n)` type method, but you should be able to wrap the default `BlockingQueue` to add that function without too much hassle, don't you think?

Alternative scenario would be to trigger an action where you put elements in the collection, where a threshold set by you would trigger the flushing.

Answer (score 1):

So this should be a threadsafe queue that lets you block on taking an arbitrary number of elements. More eyes to verify the threading code is correct would be welcome.

```
package mybq;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

public class ChunkyBlockingQueue<T> {
    protected final LinkedList<T> q = new LinkedList<T>();
    protected final Object lock = new Object();

    public void add(T t) {
        synchronized (lock) {
            q.add(t);
            lock.notifyAll();
        }
    }

    public List<T> take(int numElements) {
        synchronized (lock) {
            while (q.size() < numElements) {
                try {
                    lock.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                }
            }
            ArrayList<T> l = new ArrayList<T>(numElements);
            l.addAll(q.subList(0, numElements));
            q.subList(0, numElements).clear();
            return l;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The `notifyAll` in `add` is a bit wasteful here.  It should be a single `notify` then `take` can call `notify` again if there are still more elements left when it's done.